# What does this .jar file named Closure Compiler do?

Tags: jar, google-closure-compiler

I was looking through a repo on Github and I came across a curious folder called "closure", which had a .jar file comprised of nearly 400k lines of this:

```
504b 0304 0a00 0008 0000 7a57 1a43 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0900 0400 4d45
5441 2d49 4e46 2ffe ca00 0050 4b03 040a
0000 0808 0079 571a 4393 e765 1998 0000
00b8 0000 0014 0000 004d 4554 412d 494e
462f 4d41 4e49 4645 5354 2e4d 464d ccbd
0ec2 2018 85e1 9d84 7b60 d401 028d a43f
5b65 b531 7170 ff42 3f2b 4d0b 046a 13ef
5e8c 8beb 734e de01 bc7b 60de f81d 5376
c177 4c09 4949 efff a48f 609f c88a 95b1
```

After Googling it, I understand that Closure Compiler is a "true JavaScript compiler" that streamlines your JS code, but I'm just really curious as to what this .jar file is exactly, and was wondering if someone could give me a quick explanation.

Thank you.

For reference: https://github.com/juliandescottes/piskel/blob/master/build/closure/closure_compiler_20130823.jar

Comment: The listing does not really add any useful information to this question.

Comment: This question offers little value to other readers.

Comment: do you even know what a `.jar` file is? What does Google tell you it is? Did you even read the description of the `jar` tag?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Without decompiling to verify, we can only go off of naming. However that looks like a build of [Closure-compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/).

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/gettingstarted_app) has a quickstart guide that shows how to use the jar file to compile source.